# How can time be slowed down for two moving bodies simultaneously?

Tags: spacetime, time-dilation

I am very confused now, after reading lot of articles and watching videos on special relativity.
Let's assume there are only two bodies in universe one is moving at 80% of speed of light. Which means from the perspective of still body time for moving body is slowed down. But since we know that motion is relative which means other body can equally say that I am still and the other body is moving which means time is slowed down for the other body. How is it possible? Isn't it creating a paradox?

Comment: That is precisely correct, self-consistent, and non-paradoxical.

Comment: @DanDan0101 Which means when the bodies pass by each other then at that moment elapsed time on clocks of both bodies will be same?